# Divide Pandas DF cell by condition and save specific words

Tags: python, pandas, string, dataframe, conditional-statements

I have a pandas data frame with a text column looking like this:

```
                         A

0  61.11% no_label ; 32.22% Area_1 ; 5.56% Area_2
1  58.97% Area_3 ; 41.03% no_label
2  100% no_label
3  80.49% Area_1 ; 14.63% Area_3
```

I need to receive a column from this with the biggest percentage in a row and a name of the area of this number or the second-biggest percentage and its area if the biggest number belongs to 'no_label'. Like this one from the previous example:

```
         A

0  32.22% Area_1
1  58.97% Area_3
2  100% no_label
3  80.49% Area_1
```

Or it could be the second column, it does not matter:

```
                       A                                          B

0  61.11% no_label ; 32.22% Area_1 ; 5.56% Area_2           32.22% Area_1
1  58.97% Area_3 ; 41.03% no_label                          58.97% Area_3
2  100% no_label                                            100% no_label
3  80.49% Area_1 ; 14.63% Area_3                            80.49% Area_1
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

We can try the following. This code uses `pandas.DataFrame.apply` to apply a function to every cell in a column. Each cell has a string in it. We split each string by the separator `;`, and if there are multiple strings, we sort from lowest to highest by the percentage in that part of the string. The sorting is done by a function in `key`, which takes the string up until the `%` character and converts it to a float.

```py
import io
import pandas as pd

data = """\
61.11% no_label ; 32.22% Area_1 ; 5.56% Area_2
58.97% Area_3 ; 41.03% no_label
100% no_label
80.49% Area_1 ; 14.63% Area_3"""
df = pd.DataFrame(io.StringIO(data), columns=["A"])
df.head()

def get_largest_or_second_largest_percentage(string):
    """Given a string of data, return the largest percentage, 
    the second-largest if the largest has label 'no_label',
    the only percentage if there is one data point,
    or an empty string if there is no data.
    """
    if not string:
        return ""
    parts = [p.strip() for p in string.split(";")]
    # If there is only one item, don't bother sorting.
    if len(parts) == 1:
        return parts[0]
    # Sort from lowest to highest percentage.
    # Assumes that the percentage is before the % symbol.
    parts.sort(key=lambda s: float(s.split("%")[0]))
    # Return second-largest if the largest has label 'no_label'.
    if "no_label" in parts[-1]:
        return parts[-2]
    return parts[-1]  # return largest otherwise.

df.loc[:, "B"] = df.loc[:, "A"].apply(get_largest_or_second_largest_percentage)

print(df.head())
```

The output is

```
                                                  A              B
0  61.11% no_label ; 32.22% Area_1 ; 5.56% Area_2\n  32.22% Area_1
1                 58.97% Area_3 ; 41.03% no_label\n  58.97% Area_3
2                                   100% no_label\n  100% no_label
3                     80.49% Area_1 ; 14.63% Area_3  80.49% Area_1
```

Comment: Great! If this answered your question, please click the green checkmark to mark this as the correct answer.